# jQuery Calendar check-out date +2

Tags: jquery, datepicker

By doing some research I found a bit of code and adopted it to make it work on my site. The code should prevent users from selecting a check-out date lower then the check-in date.

The basics of the code already works, but

1) I like to add two 2 more days to my check-out date. endDate: '+2d' doesn't seem to work.

2) How to make this code vice-versa? When I first select the check-out date, its still possible to select a day higher then the check-out date as check-in date.

'#vfb-field-2' is check-in date

'#vfb-field-3' is check-out date

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
setTimeout ( function() {
$(document).on('change', '#vfb-field-2', function () {
var startdate = $(this).val();
var endDate = $('#vfb-field-3').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    endDate: '+2d',
});
endDate.datepicker("setStartDate", startdate);
});
}, 150 ); 
} );
```

Comment: for 2nd question, you need to attach for #vbf-field-3 also: 
     $(document).on('change', '#vfb-field-3', function () {

Comment: Ohh. Thank you. That works fine.
Just need to figure out how I can add two more days to the check-out date. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code :

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#indatepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        inline: true,
        minDate: 'dateToday',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){

            var outDate =  $("#indatepicker").datepicker("getDate"); 
            outDate.setDate(outDate.getDate()+2);
            $("#outdatepicker").datepicker("option","minDate",outDate);
        }
    });
        $( "#outdatepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){

            var outDate =  $("#outdatepicker").datepicker("getDate"); 
            outDate.setDate(outDate.getDate()-2);
            $("#indatepicker").datepicker("option","maxDate",outDate);
        }
        });

      } );
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>check in Date: <input type="text" id="indatepicker"> check Out Date: <input type="text" id="outdatepicker"></p>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hello, thnak you for helping me out! But somehow, it does not work for me. Maybe it helps: this is form plugin for wordpress and the code I'm injecting through the JS of my theme. Don't know if that makes a difference.

The code I originally posted does indeed work. When using yours (of course I changed the IDs) nothing happens.

Comment: your date pickers already working right? then just add on select part only.

Comment: just copy my code and past in separate HTML file and open it in your browser let's check your requirements meets or not then take those syntax part only.

Comment: Hmmm, adopting it to my needs, it won't work anymore :( I changed the ID's matching to my needs.